# Determine number of selected dates

Tags: date, sapui5

I'm new to SAP Fiori, with SAPUI5. For a simple leave application, I need to count the number of days in between the start date and end date, using JS and it all should be under mobile library (`sap.m`). I used `sap.m.DatePicker` to get the date values.

I've tried to use a for-loop, but the incrementation of date value seems to be a problem. So can you please suggest a method to solve the situation.

Comment: When selecting date intervals, consider to use `sap.m.DateRangeSelection` instead of `.DatePicker`. See _[DatePicker From and To](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53524645/5846045)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi,

```
        var y=sap.ui.getCore().byId("DP-FromDate")
        var x=sap.ui.getCore().byId("DP-ToDate")
        var c=y.getDateValue()
        var d=x.getDateValue()
        var e=(d-c)/(60*60*24*1000);
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("TF-Effective").setValue(e);
```

Gotcha.

I dont know why Math.functions didnt work with sapui5.
Anyway thanks for your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

> i need to count the no of days in between the start date and end date

If I understand correctly, you simply want to get the difference between 2 dates. Correct me if I am wrong.
You can do someting like this :

```
<DatePicker
  id="startDate"
  placeholder="Enter Start Date"/>
<DatePicker
  id="endDate"
  placeholder="Enter End Date"/>
<Button type="Accept" text="Submit" press="onPress" />
```

And in onPress :

```
onPress : function(){

          var startDate=this.getView().byId("startDate").getValue();
          var endDate=this.getView().byId("endDate").getValue();
          var sDate = new Date(startDate);
          var eDate = new Date(endDate);
          var diff = Math.abs(eDate.getTime() - sDate.getTime());
          var diffD = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
          alert(diffD) //Difference between the 2 dates.
        }
```

Comment: Hi, you are right. But i'm not able use those Math.abs,etc.. tools to calculate. Do i need to add anything else to get avail those functions?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: That error message always comes with if we use something not declared. or from an library which has not been called.

Comment: Ideally you don't have to add anything else. I created http://jsbin.com/dutidaqayo/1/edit?html,css,js,output. Check if you can find the error. You need to check on which line you are getting the "uncaught error"

Comment: Yeah man. warm thanks for your work. I've seen it working good. But it may be with my side, in sapui5 it might need to enable something where i'm not familiar with.

Comment: The `Math` class is standard Javascript, no need to declare anything. The `Undefined is not a function` error must be coming from something different. If you debug the `onPress` method, can you check if every variable gets assigned correctly?