# How can I prevent dates being selected which are prior to that in another input?

Tags: sapui5, date-range

In a form, I have two `DatePicker` fields which are `From` and `To`. In this case user should not be able to choose a value for `To` less than what he/she choose for the `From` field.

I just wanted to know is there any SAPUI5 native way to do this comparison and validate the `DatePicker` fields? In the image blow, you can see that the `From` has a greater value than the `To`, which is wrong! In this case, I need to show the validation error around the fields.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have the following 2 `DatePicker` objects in your xml view file:

```
<m:DatePicker id="__input_validFrom" 
   value="{path: 'ZValidFrom', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date'}"
   fieldGroupIds="fieldGroup1" 
   change="handleValidFromChange"/>

<m:DatePicker id="__input_validTo" 
   value="{path: 'ZValidTo', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date'}" 
   fieldGroupIds="fieldGroup1" 
   change="handleValidToChange" />
```

These 2 fields show the date in a suitable format as we set the type to `sap.ui.model.type.Date`.

Now we have to play with constraints of the `sap.ui.model.type.Date` in the `onChange` event handler:

```
handleValidFromChange: function (oEvent) {
    var oDatePicker = oEvent.getSource(),
        sValue = oDatePicker.getValue(),
        sToDatePicker = "__input_validTo",          
        oToDatePicker = this.byId(sToDatePicker);
    oToDatePicker.getBinding("value").setType(new sap.ui.model.type.Date(null, {
        minimum: new Date(sValue)
    }), "string");
},
handleValidToChange: function (oEvent) {
    var oDatePicker = oEvent.getSource(),
        sValue = oDatePicker.getValue(),
        sFromDatePicker = "__input_validFrom",
        oFromDatePicker = this.byId(sFromDatePicker);
    oFromDatePicker.getBinding("value").setType(new sap.ui.model.type.Date(null, {
        maximum: new Date(sValue)
    }), "string");
}
```

As soon as user change value in one of fields we change the constraints in the other field.

Notes:

1. Please note that we cannot directly bind the constraints to a model.
2. By applying this solution you need to use validation on date pickers to see some validation state text.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any SAPUI5 native way to do this

Yes, take a look at the **[*Date Range Selection*](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/date-range-selection/).**

### Sample

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataModel",
  "sap/ui/core/Messaging",
], async (XMLView, ODataModel, Messaging) => {
  "use strict";
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: document.getElementById("myxmlfragment").textContent,
    models: new ODataModel({
      serviceUrl: "https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(myservice))/",
      autoExpandSelect: true,
    }),
  });
  Messaging.registerObject(control, true);
  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script defer id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-on-init="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compat-version="edge"
  data-sap-ui-exclude-jquery-compat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-wait-for-theme="init"
></script>
<script id="myxmlfragment" type="text/xml">
  <mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    core:require="{
      ODataV4DateTimeOffset: 'sap/ui/model/odata/type/DateTimeOffset',
      DateInterval: 'sap/ui/model/type/DateInterval'
    }"
    height="100%"
  >
    <App autoFocus="false">
      <Page showHeader="false" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin">
        <layout:VerticalLayout binding="{/People('russellwhyte')/Trips(0)}">
          <Text text="{ path: 'StartsAt', targetType: 'any' }" />
          <Text text="{ path: 'EndsAt', targetType: 'any' }" />
          <DateRangeSelection
            placeholder="&lt;From> - &lt;To>"
            width="16rem"
            value="{
              parts: [
                {
                  path: 'StartsAt',
                  formatOptions: { UTC: true },
                  type: 'ODataV4DateTimeOffset'
                },
                {
                  path: 'EndsAt',
                  formatOptions: { UTC: true },
                  type: 'ODataV4DateTimeOffset'
                }
              ],
              type: 'DateInterval',
              formatOptions: { UTC: true },
              parameters: { $$noPatch: true }
            }"
          />
        </layout:VerticalLayout>
      </Page>
    </App>
  </mvc:View>
</script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

<sup>**Note:** the above sample makes use of `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel`. The same approach can be applied to the V2 model which, however, requires explicitly enabling two-way binding with e.g. `defaultBindingMode: "TwoWay"` in the model settings. Additionally, binding definitions also differ in V2. Please review the documentation topic ["Dates, Times, Timestamps, and Time Zones"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/6c9e61dc157a40c19460660ece8368bc) and adjust the data settings accordingly. The above sample makes use of the entity properties with `Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"` which is not really suitable for the `DateRangeSelection` control. The property type should be rather `"Edm.Date"` in OData V4 or `"Edm.DateTime"` with `sap:display-format="Date"` in V2.</sup>

### Result

[image: sap.m.DateRangeSelection]

**This resolves the given problems:**

- User needs to pick two date values. ✔️
- User should **not** be able to choose `To` less than `From`. ✔️
- Looking for "UI5 native way" to solve this. ✔️

Use it in combination with the [**binding type:** `sap.ui.model.type.Date*Interval`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.type.DateInterval) to enable:

- Two-way data binding ✔️
- Format options ✔️
- Input validation with standard UI messages ✔️

**Compared to the custom implementation** in JavaScript with two `DatePicker`s, the `DateRangeSelection` control allows:

- Less clicks for the user ✔️
- Zero custom JS code to handle date ranges ✔️

---

See the documentation topic [**"Dates, Times, Timestamps, and Time Zones"**](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/6c9e61dc157a40c19460660ece8368bc) (must-read IMO).

Answer (score 1):

By using the [`change`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/events/change) event on the "from" picker we can then use the method [`setMinDate()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/methods/setMinDate) for the "To" picker based on the date picked so the user can only select dates after the date selected.

On our XML view we can have both [`sap.m.DatePicker`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker):

```
<DatePicker id="DP1" placeholder="Enter Date ..." change="handleChange"/>
<DatePicker id="DP2" placeholder="Enter Date ..."/>
```

And in our controller we can then apply the logic:

```
handleChange: function(oControlEvent) {
   //get date picked from first picker
   var sDatePicked = oControlEvent.getSource().getDateValue();
   //set minimum date on second picker
   this.getView().byId("DP2").setMinDate(sDatePicked).setValue();
}
```

By applying this method we can now get the new value from the first [`sap.m.DatePicker`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker) and apply it to the "To" Date Picker by using the [`setMinDate()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/methods/setMinDate) method and reset its value so the user has to select a new date.